# difference between <video src=""> </video > and <video> <source> </video>?

Tags: html, html5-video

Could you please explain me the difference between

```
<video src=""> </video>
```

and

```
<video>
    <source src="">
</video>
```

?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

By using `<video> <source> </video>`.
You can add multiple source elements.
Multiple source elements can link to different video files. The browser will use the first recognized format.

```html
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src=http://example.com/foo.webm type=video/webm> 
    <source src=http://example.com/foo.ogv type=video/ogg> 
    <source src=http://example.com/foo.mp4 type=video/mp4>
    <source src=http://example.com/foo.3gp type=video/3gp>
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: what happens if the element has both src attribute and source elements as childrens. which one has priority