# Jquery hack to change video for safari and other browsers

Tags: jquery, video, safari

I am adding a video in my website but its not working on safari. I am using 'webm' video format. and i need to put 'mov' video format in safari.

[image]

Please suggest a hack in JQuery so that when safari opens, then 'mov' video is played and for other browsers 'webm' video is played.

Comment: jQuery Browser documentation https://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/

Comment: This is my code for both videos 

I need to play "newVideo2" for "safari" browser and "newVideo" for rest of the browsers

Comment: You shouldn't use a hack. You should provide both webm and mov sources in the `<video>` tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [difference between <video src=""> </video > and <video> <source> </source></video>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39179834/difference-between-video-src-video-and-video-source-source-vide)

Comment: "<video autoplay loop muted playsinline="" preload="auto" id="newVideo">
 <source src="assets/vid/FinalLandingVideo.webm" type="video/webm"></source>
</video>
                        
<video autoplay loop muted playsinline="" preload="auto" id="newVideo2">
 <source src="assets/vid/FinalLandingVideo.mov" type="video/mov"></source>
</video>"

This is the "video" code i am using

Comment: Please suggest JQuery code so that on safari the 'mov' video is played and on other browsers 'webm' video is played

Comment: @GunjanSharma Try this out by looking at the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/f688e7vh/

Comment: Do I need to add my "class" or anything instead of 'source' ?
and do i need to write video tags for both of the videos 'webm' and 'mov' ?

Because I have written video tag for both and added the code written in javascript as it is as in jsfiddle, but still its not working

Comment: You don't need any jQuery stuff. Just put two `<source></source>` blocks in one `<video>` tag, one with the webm, and one with the mov. The browser will use the first one it recognizes. i.e. `<video autoplay loop muted playsinline="" preload="auto" id="newVideo"><source src="assets/vid/FinalLandingVideo.webm" type="video/webm"></source><source src="assets/vid/FinalLandingVideo.mov" type="video/mov"></source></video>`

Comment: @Shiladitya On chrome and firefox its working but on safari the 'mov' video is played and the error of 'webm' video overlays it as i have added video tags for both videos separately.

Comment: @ceejayoz when i put both source, its not looking good on safari as a box with play tag (it is of 'webm' video which can't be played on safari) overlays the mov video

Comment: @GunjanSharma Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/ajwf6yoy/

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5 `<video>` tag accepts multiple `<source>` tags. Browsers will play the first one they recognize. All you should need is:

```
<video autoplay loop muted playsinline="" preload="auto" id="newVideo">
    <source src="assets/vid/FinalLandingVideo.webm" type="video/webm"></source>
    <source src="assets/vid/FinalLandingVideo.mov" type="video/mov"></source>
</video>
```

Comment: I have added an image above on tag "Image of Video view in safari" please have a look. The 'webm' video is overlaying the 'mov' video on safari browser

Comment: No doubt the videos are working on both of the browsers. But Please suggest any solution so that the videos do not overlay on safari. .

Comment: @GunjanSharma I don't think that has anything to do with the webm version. Try setting the `poster` attribute on your `<video>` tag to provide a thumbnail preview. That looks like it's just the default look when the video file hasn't been played yet.

Comment: But I need to 'autoplay' the video as the website is opened and I have used 'webm' video as 'mov' video is not supported in 'chrome' and 'firefox' browser

Comment: @GunjanSharma If it has audio, you can't. https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/

Comment: @GunjanSharma I'm also not sure why you're bringing up reasons for using webm (again). I'm fully aware that mov isn't supported in some browsers. That's why you use the two `<source>` tags.

Answer (score -1):

Detect which browser you are viewing on and then display the proper video

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1) {//play .mov}
else{//play .webm}
```

Comment: How should it be done? [edit] sorry just saw your above comment, much better agreed